# “Website Cannot Be Found”

Tags: domains

I wasn't sure if this was the right place to ask this, but here goes. I was editing a file using filezilla (it's early in the morning where I am, but I wanted to get my project done so I [was] working into the wee hours of the day), and saved, but it didn't save. In fact, it logged me out. I tried logging back in, but it said something weird (I don't remember what). I tried opening my website domain, and it Chrome told me that "Oops! Google Chrome could not find youthunemployment.org". What did I do? Was my site hacked? Can you guys help me? Thank you very much!

My website is http://www.youthunemployment.org

I used cmd to ping my site, and I got a response. This is my first website I've set up, so I'm really confused.

My host is 000webhost.com, and my domain service was namecheap.com.

I can still connect (and edit, or so it seems) on c9.io. But I can't view them from the regular browser!

I mentioned Google Chrome. The problem is also on IE. I haven't checked other browsers.

Comment: Works for me. Maybe clearing your browser cache will help. It's also possible that there was a temporary problem on the server. Especially when the site is new, there is the possibility that the URL cannot be resolved some times.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your [DNS](http://www.iptools.com/dnstools.php?tool=dns&user_data=www.youthunemployment.org&type=A) settings through [iptools.com](http://iptools.com) and everything looks to be ok and pointing in the right direction - have you tried contacting 000webhost.com?